# async Task sometimes does not execute all lines of code

Tags: c#

I have a Task that sometimes runs fine and sometimes it gets to UpdateNewsMessages (which is normal sync void) runs all code inside UpdateNewsMessages but never gets to set CheckingNews to true. The function acts as if there was return or something.

Is there something I don't know about async? Please let me know if you need more info.

```
public bool CheckingNews = false;  

public async Task GetNews()
    {
        CheckingNews = false;

        List<NewsMessage> newsMessages = await new Downloader().GetNewsMessages();
        if (newsMessages != null)
            Resource.UI.News.UpdateNewsMessages(newsMessages);

        CheckingNews = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your UpdateNewsMessages is async method. Add await before that method if you are using the same DB context. At one time for one DB context you cannot fire 2 queries. For every async method there should be an await.

Comment: UpdateNewsMessages is not async but I added await to where I call GetNews and I started getting error messages.
So the problem was that the program kept running after encountering my logic error instead of crashing and displaying error message.
Thank you for help!

Comment: Yes, every async method call should have an await method used for its calling, or if you want to run it parallel call the methods and return into variables and await the variable where you need it. Glad I could help.